# Find values for which the result of division change in integer in python

Tags: python, bigdata

This might be a really silly question but I'm a bit stuck. I have three columns with data. Column C is the result of the division of Column A/Column B. The result of this simple operation gives me real numbers running from 0 to 15. I want to compute for which value in column A, the values in column C change in multiple (from 1, to 2, to 3). i.e.

```
A             B              C=A/B

0.0     894.57         0.0
1.0     894.579620994  0.00111784348372
11.0    894.579622195  0.0122962783044
21.0    894.579625847  0.0234747130309
30.0    894.579632967  0.0335353040629
40.0    894.57964499   0.0447137381496
 ...        ...            ...
881.0   894.579705447  0.984820016188
891.0   894.579703891  0.995998451703
901.0   894.57970588   1.00717688326
911.0   894.579707084  1.01835531567
 ...       ...             ...
1781.0  894.579658537  1.99087916096
1791.0  894.57965582   2.00205760141 
1801.0  894.579658252  2.01323603034
```

What I want in other words is to find the values of A for which the values in C change the integer. In this case it would be the value for which it changes from 0.99 to 1., so it would be: 901; then from 1 to 2 it would be 1791, and so on. 
Any ideas are welcome. I thought I could find the residuals (%) but I cannot come up of how.

Comment: where is this data stored? is this a database or a csv file or ? And you can do for example by taking the integer part of column C, checking if it is equal to `i` and when it is, iterate `i` (`i += 1`) and keep going.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not an elegant solution, but couldn't you just compare the numbers at the beginning of each entry (assuming your data is consistent)? This would make things very easy. The example below assumes your data is separated by whitespace (as in your post) and is stored in a file called "data."

---

Program:

```
data = open("data", "r")
last = "0"
for element in data:
    a, b, c = element.split()
    if c[0] != last:
        print(a)
        last = c[0]
```

---

Output:

```
901.0
1791.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

```
A = 1      # adapt this to your data
B = 894.57 # adapt this to your data

lastInt = -1
for i in range(0,1000):
   C = A / B
   newInt = int(C)
   if newInt!=lastInt:
       print "CHANGE: from {} to {}. A is {}".format(lastInt, newInt, A)
       lastInt = newInt
   A += 10  # adapt this to your data
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get the data out since you said you tried `%` and assuming that the data are not strings, wouldn't this work? A simple if statement with a checker that increments?

```
number_to_check = 1
if c >= number_to_check:
    number_to_check += 1
    print(a)
```